# haskell safecopy example

Tags: haskell

(src http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/safecopy/0.6.1/doc/html/Data-SafeCopy.html)

If you rename Contacts data type into data Contacts_v0

```
type Name     = String
type Address  = String
data Contacts = Contacts [(Name, Address)]
instance SafeCopy Contacts where
     putCopy (Contacts list) = contain $ safePut list
     getCopy = contain $ Contacts <$> safeGet
```

How is Contacts_v0 suppose to be assigned to old existing data?

```
type Name = String
type Address = String
type Phone = String

data Contacts_v0 = Contacts_v0 [(Name, Address)]
instance SafeCopy Contacts_v0 where
     putCopy (Contacts_v0 list) = contain $ safePut list
     getCopy = contain $ Contacts_v0 <$> safeGet

data Contact = Contact { name    :: Name
                        , address :: Address
                        , phone   :: Phone }
instance SafeCopy Contact where
    putCopy Contact{..} = contain $ do safePut name; safePut address; safePut phone
    getCopy = contain $ Contact <$> safeGet <*> safeGet <*> safeGet

data Contacts = Contacts [Contact]
instance SafeCopy Contacts where
     version = 2
     kind = extension
     putCopy (Contacts contacts) = contain $ safePut contacts
     getCopy = contain $ Contacts <$> safeGet

instance Migrate Contacts where
     type MigrateFrom Contacts = Contacts_v0
     migrate (Contacts_v0 contacts) = Contacts [ Contact{ name    = name
                                                        , address = address
                                                        , phone   = "" }
                                               | (name, address) <- contacts ]
```

From the above library documentation I am trying to do this.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards, TypeFamilies #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Data.SafeCopy

type Name = String
type Address = String
type Phone = String

data Contacts = Contacts [(Name, Address)] deriving (Show)
instance SafeCopy Contacts where
     putCopy (Contacts list) = contain $ safePut list
     getCopy = contain $ Contacts <$> safeGet

data Contacts_v0 = Contacts_v0 [(Name, Address)] deriving (Show)
instance SafeCopy Contacts_v0 where
     putCopy (Contacts_v0 list) = contain $ safePut list
     getCopy = contain $ Contacts_v0 <$> safeGet

data Contact = Contact { name :: Name, address :: Address, phone :: Phone } deriving (Show)
instance SafeCopy Contact where
    putCopy Contact{..} = contain $ do safePut name; safePut address; safePut phone
    getCopy = contain $ Contact <$> safeGet <*> safeGet <*> safeGet

{-
data Contacts = Contacts [Contact]
instance SafeCopy Contacts where
     version = 2
     kind = extension
     putCopy (Contacts contacts) = contain $ safePut contacts
     getCopy = contain $ Contacts <$> safeGet

instance Migrate Contacts where
     type MigrateFrom Contacts = Contacts_v0
     migrate (Contacts_v0 contacts) = Contacts [ Contact{ name    = name, address = address, phone   = "" }
                                               | (name, address) <- contacts ]
-}

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let test = Contacts [("gert","home")]
    print test
    --let testNew = how do you migrate test using migrate?
    --print testNew
```

Note that it would make more sense to me if they renamed the new one to Contacts_v2 instead of renaming the old one.

Maybe I should rephrase the question, when is safecopy useful?

Comment: Can you state a clear question and give some introduction in text to your problem?

Comment: `How is Contacts_v0 suppose to be assigned to old existing data?` Don't know how to be more clear, working on a introduction please wait.

Comment: -3 seriously? We have became a bit harse.  Sure it was light on intro but it is a real issue and it appears anyone familiar with SafeCopy could set Gert straight.

Comment: The code examples in this question are directly from the example given in the link. Therefore, it seems that the question is to give a runnable program that supports a legacy datatype using `Data.SafeCopy`. That is not at all clear and should be reflected in the question. It could be beneficial to remove the code example since it might be misleading, or atleast state that it is the sample code from the library documentation.

Comment: The link was mentioned in the first line? should it be in the title? I am writing a main just a sec.

Comment: So if the src link was not clear enough I put !!!LIBRARY DOCUMENTATION!!! just in case. Can I have my 0 back now pleas.

Comment: doh! -4 adding a better explanation does not seem to be beneficial :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards, TypeFamilies#-}
import Control.Applicative
import Data.SafeCopy
import Data.Binary
import Data.Serialize.Get
import Data.Serialize.Put

type Name = String
type Address = String
type Phone = String

data Contact = Contact { name :: Name, address :: Address, phone :: Phone } deriving (Show)
instance Binary Contact where
    put Contact{..} = do put name; put address; put phone
    get = do name <- get; address <- get; phone <- get; return Contact{..}
instance SafeCopy Contact where
    putCopy Contact{..} = contain $ do safePut name; safePut address; safePut phone
    getCopy = contain $ Contact <$> safeGet <*> safeGet <*> safeGet

data Contacts = Contacts [Contact] deriving (Show)
instance Binary Contacts where
    put (Contacts set) = put set
    get = fmap Contacts get
instance SafeCopy Contacts where
     version = 2
     kind = extension
     putCopy (Contacts contacts) = contain $ safePut contacts
     getCopy = contain $ Contacts <$> safeGet
instance Migrate Contacts where
     type MigrateFrom Contacts = Contacts_v0
     migrate (Contacts_v0 contacts) = Contacts[Contact{name=name,address=address,phone=""}|(name,address)<-contacts]

data Contacts_v0 = Contacts_v0 [(Name, Address)] deriving (Show)
instance Binary Contacts_v0 where
    put (Contacts_v0 set) = put set
    get = fmap Contacts_v0 get
instance SafeCopy Contacts_v0 where
    putCopy (Contacts_v0 list) = contain $ safePut list
    getCopy = contain $ Contacts_v0 <$> safeGet

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- 
    -- instance Binary 
    --
    let c' = Contacts[Contact{name="gert",address="home",phone="test"},Contact{name="gert2",address="home2",phone="test2"}]
    let e' = encode c'
    print e'
    let d' = decode e'
    print (d':: Contacts)

    let c = Contacts_v0 [("gert_v0","home_v0"),("gert2_v0","home2_v0")]
    let e = encode c
    print e
    let d = decode e
    print (d:: Contacts_v0)
    --can not do print (d:: Contacts) meaning you are screwed

    --
    -- instance SafeCopy
    --
    let c'' = Contacts_v0 [("gert_v0","home_v0"),("gert2_v0","home2_v0")]
    let e'' = runPut (safePut c'')
    print e''
    let d'' = runGet safeGet e''
    case d'' of
        Left _ -> print "error"
        Right d'' -> print (d'':: Contacts)
    --can do print (d:: Contacts) or print (d:: Contacts_v0) meaning you are safed
```